# why my e.item in radgrid ItemCommand event always null

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm using RadGrid control, and I cread a group of command button, as insert , update, save , delete. When I click insert button, RadGrid can enter insert mode, But when I click save button after entering data, the e.item is always null? how can i fetch Radgrid values of item in editmode/insermode ?

Here is the partial code:
asp:

```
  <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridLandBlock" runat="server" Culture="zh-CN" GroupPanelPosition="Top"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
       Width="1000px" Height="500px"  Skin="Metro" 
      OnNeedDataSource="RadGridLandBlock_NeedDataSource" 
      OnItemCommand ="RadGridLandBlock_ItemCommand" 
      OnItemCreated ="RadGridLandBlock_ItemCreated"  
       OnInsertCommand="RadGridLandBlock_InsertCommand" 
      >
      <ClientSettings>
          <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"  />
          <Scrolling AllowScroll="true"  />
          <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="true" AllowResizeToFit="true" />    
      </ClientSettings>
      <MasterTableView ClientDataKeyNames="PK_Land"  DataKeyNames="PK_Land" EditMode="InPlace" CommandItemDisplay="Top"    >
          <NoRecordsTemplate>
              No Record
          </NoRecordsTemplate>
          <CommandItemSettings ShowRefreshButton="false"  />
          <CommandItemTemplate >
              <div id="RadGridCommand" style="padding: 10px 10px;" >
                  <telerik:RadButton ID="InsertBtn" CommandName="InsertBtn"    CommandArgument  ='<%#Eval ("PK_Land") %>' runat="server" Skin="Metro" Text="插入"  Enabled='<%#! RadGridLandBlock.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>' ></telerik:RadButton>
                  <telerik:RadButton ID="DeleteBtn" CommandName="DeleteBtn"    runat="server" Skin="Metro"  Text ="Delete"  Enabled='<%#! RadGridLandBlock.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>' OnClientClicked="confirmDelete" ></telerik:RadButton>
                  <telerik:RadButton ID="EditBtn" CommandName="EditBtn" runat="server" Skin="Metro" Text="Edit"  Enabled='<%# RadGridLandBlock.EditIndexes.Count == 0 %>'></telerik:RadButton>
                  <telerik:RadButton ID="SaveBtn" CommandName="SaveBtn" runat="server" Skin="Metro"  Text="Save"  Enabled='<%# RadGridLandBlock.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>' ></telerik:RadButton>
                  <telerik:RadButton ID="CancelBtn" CommandName="CancelBtn" runat="server" Skin="Metro"  Text="Cancel"  Enabled='<%# RadGridLandBlock.EditIndexes.Count > 0 ||RadGridLandBlock.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>' ></telerik:RadButton>
              </div>
          </CommandItemTemplate>
          <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_Land" DataType="System.Guid"  HeaderText="PK_Land" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PK_Land" UniqueName="PK_Land">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_BookID" DataType="System.Int32"  HeaderText="PK_BookID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PK_BookID" UniqueName="PK_BookID">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LandBlockName" DataType="System.Char"  HeaderText="LandName" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="LandBlockName" UniqueName="LandBlockName">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CapacityRate" DataType="System.Char"  HeaderText="Capacity" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="CapacityRate" UniqueName="CapacityRate">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>       
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_period" DataType="System.Int32"  HeaderText="PK_period" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="PK_period" UniqueName="PK_period">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>       
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_useridLastEditor" DataType="System.Int32"  HeaderText="PK_useridLastEditor" ReadOnly="false" SortExpression="PK_useridLastEditor" UniqueName="PK_useridLastEditor">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>       
          </Columns>
      </MasterTableView>
  </telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#

```
 protected void RadGridLandBlock_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //insert btn clicked
        if (e.CommandName == "InsertBtn")
        {
            LabelTest.Text = "insert btn from itemcommand is fired";
            RadGridLandBlock.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true;

            RadGridLandBlock.Rebind();
        }
//Save btn clicked
        if (e.CommandName=="SaveBtn")
        {
            LabelTest.Text = "SaveBtn from itemcommand is fired";
                myCnn = new SqlConnection(myCnnstring);
                myCnn.Open();
                mysql = "insert into ld_landblock (PK_bookID,landblockname,capacityrate,pk_period,pk_userIDlasteditor) " +
                " values(@pk_bookid, @landblockname,@capacityrate,@pk_period,@pk_userIDlasteditor)";
                mycmd = new SqlCommand(mysql, myCnn);
                GridEditFormItem editItem = e.Item as GridEditFormItem;
                mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_bookid", Convert.ToInt32((editItem.FindControl("PK_BookID") as TextBox).Text));//HERE IS THE ERROR OCCURED)
                mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue.......
  }
}



    protected void RadGridLandBlock_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
       // RadGridLandBlock.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = false;
        PK_bookID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PK_BookID"]);
        PK_period = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PK_Period"]);
        (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = GetGridDatatable();

    }


    protected void RadGridLandBlock_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...
The description as per the comment in the code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("A");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            dt.Rows.Add("1 " + i);

        ViewState["Da"] = dt;

        rg.DataSource = dt;
        rg.DataBind();

    }
}

protected void rg_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (e.CommandName == "SaveTrigger")
    {

        // Variable
        string value = string.Empty;
        TextBox txt = null;

        // Check
        if (e.Item is GridDataInsertItem)
        {
            // Set Init Insert Items 
            GridDataInsertItem item = e.Item as GridDataInsertItem;

            // Get Textbox from Insert New Item
            txt = item.FindControl("txt") as TextBox;
        }
        else
        {

            // This will get the first line of the Edit Item
            GridEditableItem editItem = rg.EditItems[0] as GridEditableItem;

            // Or
            // This will get be using Index Number through the button which you press save
            // GridDataItem editItem = rg.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex] as GridDataItem;
            txt = editItem.FindControl("txt") as TextBox;
        }

        Response.Write(txt.Text.Trim());           
    }
}

protected void rg_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    rg.DataSource = ViewState["Da"] as DataTable;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but it says Argument Out Of Range. "GridEditableItem editItem = rg.EditItems[0] as GridEditableItem;"

Comment: @HenryLee Just wondering your item is it in Edit Mode ? Maybe you can do a checking on `RadGridLandBlock.EditItem.Count > 0`.. That error mean you don't have editable item in your RadGrid

Comment: Thanks. I have tried. It was 0. but  "RadGridLandBlock.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true" really make the first row of RadGrid in insert mode. I'm suspicious that the insert/edit mode is in Client-Side, not in datasource side, so "e.item" doesn't work? But Radgrid is a server control, the value in insert/edit row suppose to be fetched, I think.  Any help?

Comment: the part of edit button is ok. RadGridLandBlock.EditItem.Count =1. But the part of insert button still doesn't work.

Comment: @HenryLee Was sleeping cause the last reply i replied at 11pm... I have updated the answer.. You may have a look on it